VSCode Keybinding to Focus or Create Specific Terminals (R Interactive and zsh) on Mac
I’m trying to set up VSCode on my Mac with custom keybindings to manage terminals more effectively. I primarily work with two types of terminals: one for R (using the R extension) and another for a regular zsh shell.
Here’s what I’m aiming to achieve:
1.  When I press ctrl+2:
  • If a terminal called “R Interactive” does not exist, I want it to create a new R terminal using the command r.createRTerm.
  • If the “R Interactive” terminal already exists, I want to move focus to it.
2.  When I press ctrl+3:
  • If a zsh shell terminal doesn’t exist, I want to create a new one.
  • If a zsh terminal does exist, I want to focus on it.

I’ve tried configuring these keybindings in keybindings.json, but I’ve hit some limitations:
•   I can’t seem to conditionally check for an existing terminal by name and create or focus it accordingly.
•   VSCode’s when condition in keybindings doesn’t seem to have a way to reliably detect if a specific terminal already exists but isn’t currently focused.
Is there a way to set up these behaviors in VSCode, possibly with tasks.json or any other configuration workaround?
Any guidance on achieving this functionality or alternative suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
